# How to display XML data as xml structure?

Tags: php, xml, curl, epp

I am sending XML requests with cURL, and server is responding with XML data, which is displayed as single line string, I want to represent data as classical XML structure like this:

```
<command>
    <check>
      <domain:check>
        <domain:name>domena1.hr</domain:name>
        <domain:name>domena2.hr</domain:name>
      </domain:check>
    </check>
    <clTRID>05106558-94309643</clTRID>
  </command>
```

Data is returned as curl_exec, and in string format, only with values.

Comment: If you're viewing the xml on a web browser, view the source code, if the xml is well encoded, it will maintain it's structure.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is called pretty printing. Semantically, the linefeeds and indent is irrelevant to XML.

Personally - I'd install the perl `XML::Twig` library, because one of the utilities it also installs is [`xml_pp`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm#xml_pp_-_xml_pretty-printer). Which basically does:

```
perl -e 'XML::Twig -> new ( pretty_print => 'indented' ) -> parse ( \*STDIN ) -> print;'
```

But most languages and parses can do it - just look up 'pretty print'.